# Parse SQL Developer Timestamp Format DD-MON-RRRR HH24:MI:SSXFF to Java Timestamp

Tags: java, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using sql developer and developing in Java.

I want to be able to take a csv file which was created using sql developer export and to parse it back to java Timestamp.

The Timestamp format taken from sql developer --> DataBase --> NLS is :DD-MON-RRRR HH24:MI:SSXFF

trying to use new SimpleDateFormat("DD-MON-RRRR HH24:MI:SSXFF"); throw IllegalArgumentException

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The allowable letters and their meanings are different in Java. See the documentation for [SimpleDateFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html). For example, 'R' should become 'y'.